# Is it possible to driver two parallel MOSFET by using single optocupler (TLP250)?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, driver

[image]

I am Using TLP250 to drive IRFP260N MOSFET . If i use separate driver to drive MOSFET i need two power supply . so i am looking for single drive solution for multiple mosfet .

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. It is advisable to a resistor in series with each gate to help avoid oscillations.

Careful PCB layout is also a must - keep the source inductances matched and as low as possible. Put the MOSFETs as close together as possible, wire the sources together with as short and wide track as possible and connect to your gate driver at the mid point of that track.

Answer (score 1):

The gate of a MOSFET behaves pretty much like a capacitor. When switching, whatever device is driving the gate must charge or discharge the gate.

Two capacitors (or gates) in parallel behave like a capacitor with double the size. So the worst that can happen is that the switching of the MOSFETs needs double the time; this might become a problem if they switch lots of current, and they stay longer in the active region where they must dissipate lots of power.